# MySql driver not found for Scala program

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I'm a newbie on Scala, am trying to use Spark to read from a mysql database. I'm facing a class-not-found exception whatever I do. I tried to connect without Spark, using Squeryl, Scalike, etc. Always the same problem.
Here's one example I tried :

```
logger.info("Write part")

val dataframe_mysql = spark.sqlContext
  .read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", s"jdbc:mysql://${datamart_server}:3306/vol")
  .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .option("dbtable", "company")
  .option("user", datamart_user).option("password", datamart_pwd)
  .load()

dataframe_mysql.show()
```

I tried to put the driver classname in a src/main/resources/application.conf:

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

But it didn't help. I've got :

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

I also share the sbt file to show how I add the dependencies :

```
name := "commercial-api-datamart-feed"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3" % Runtime
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.24" % Runtime
```

Spark is not mandatory but I think it's better for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running this code? You'll need to pass the MySQL JAR as `--jars`; something like `--jars /path/to/mysql.jar` if starting up `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`.

If you prefer running a single JAR, you'll need to ensure that the MySQL JAR is embedded as part of your uber JAR. I've never used SBT but you'll need to check whether the final JAR created has the MySQL classes inside it -- if not, use the relevant SBT flags to make that happen.

Comment: You're right. I'm using spark-submit, and the jar doesn't include mysql driver. (However it doesn't include the other dependencies, so why just mysql driver?). So now when I add the parameter you suggested, it works.
I still have a problem using addSbtPlugin (to find the correct version for scala 2.11) but I think I should put it as another question. Thank you!

Comment: @IoriYagami AFAIK, the reason it works for other JARs (`spark-sql`, `spark-core`) is that they are already part of the classpath when spawning up executors/driver given they are part of the Spark installation. You should see the same behaviour for any "non-Spark" JARs which your application uses. If not, it would be very surprising.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the mysql dependencies exist on all of the executors. In my environment, I use maven and specify the dependency like this inside of my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.42</version>
</dependency>
```

I then ensure that this dependency is bundled in my application jar (using the maven shade plugin), so that I don't have to place the jar on all of the executors.

Whether you use `spark` or not to access `mysql` over `jdbc`, you need to make sure the `mysql-connector` is available on your `classpath`, wherever you are executing `mysql` queries from.

Comment: Thank you @Travis for the comment. I'm sorry that I forgot to include my sbt file. I'm updating the post.