# SBT, Spark and MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm trying to create a Spark Data Frame with data extracted from SQL Server.

```
  val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "sqlserver://...")
  .option("dbtable", "table")
  .option("user", "user")
  .option("password", "passwors")
  .load()
```

I put the driver JAR in my /lib folder

```
build.sbt
lib/
  mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar
project/
src/
```

Yet, I still get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this out for example [MySql driver not found for Scala program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985232/mysql-driver-not-found-for-scala-program)

Comment: Thank you. I actually managed to find a way around by simply adding com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.2.1.jre8 to dependencies and .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") to the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass driver path along with spark-submit command, something like this has solved the problem for me:

spark-submit **--driver-class-path C:\postgresql\postgresql\42.2.5\postgresql-42.2.5.jar** --class SparkMaven.Postgres.App --master local[*] C:\eclipse-workspace\Postgres\target\Postgres-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 1):

To close the topic, we can potentially handle this in two ways:

1. passing the driver as part of the spark-submit (see Vivek's answer)
2. adding `com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.2.1.jre8` to dependencies and `.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` to the code